# PHP/Linux: Does 'kill -9' equate to SIGKILL?

Tags: php, linux, signals

I'm looking at this PHP code for doing a signal trap:

```
<?php
/*
SIGTERM for 'kill' default of -15
SIGINT for control-c
*/
    declare(ticks = 1);

    pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "signal_handler");
    pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "signal_handler");

    function signal_handler($signal) {
        switch($signal) {
            case SIGTERM:
                print "Caught SIGTERM\n";
                exit;
            case SIGKILL:
                print "Caught SIGKILL\n";
                exit;
            case SIGINT:
                print "Caught SIGINT\n";
                exit;
        }
    }

    while(1) {
        //
    }
?>
```

Can SIGKILL be equated to a number option to the 'kill' command such as 'kill -9'? If not, what conditions would cause a SIGKILL signal? Thanks!

Comment: not from PHP background, but yes its possible here is [one example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, signal 9 is SIGKILL.  You can run kill -l and see the list of signals with their number (the man page `signal(7)` has also more information).

However this `case` is useless.  SIGKILL cannot be caught by a signal handler (the man page has the details).  So there is no point in having it in the switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. "kill -9" will equates to SIGKILL. From kill man pages:

"Alternate signals may  be  specified  in  three  ways:  -9  -SIGKILL -KILL."

Also, if you look at man 7 signal:

```
           "SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal"
```

So, yes - "kill -9" will emit a SIGKILL signal.